# Does the column ordering matter in the stepwise algorithms used by R?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, model-selection, aic, stepwise-regression

Suppose I have a large data set with variables $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_p$ to predict response $y$ where $p$ is very large (however $n >> p$).

I would like to perform **forward** stepwise regression on the data using an appropriate function in R, such as `stepAIC` from the `MASS` package.

Does the order in which the data appears in the data frame matter or will we get the same model each time the algorithm is run. By this I mean that I run forward stepwise regression and I get a result. Suppose I shuffle the order of the columns in the data frame and rerun the  forward stepwise selection. Will I get a different result with the shuffled data frame?

I have experimented with small data sets and I get the same result when I shuffle the order of the variables, however I am unsure whether this will occur with very large data sets which can take several hours to run on HPC.

Comment: The variables are chosen by various criteria, depending on the form of stepwise regression you use, but none of those criteria depend on the order of the variables.  If you're going to select this method, then it will pay to review how it works so you can make wise choices and understand its output. Although this is good general advice for using any statistical procedure, it's particularly appropriate for stepwise regression, as you might have surmised from Dr. Harrell's somewhat acerbic reply.

Answer (score 2):

The results will be equally invalid no matter how your sort the columns.  See https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems

Comment: Thanks for the response, and I agree with you that there are issues with stepwise regression as mentioned in the link provided, however will the final model returned from the stepwise procedure always be the same regardless of the order of the variables in the columns?

Comment: Why use an invalid statistical procedure?  Have you bootstrapped the entire process to show how volatile the feature selection procedure really is?

Comment: I am just a student working on a small project and I am performing this procedure because this is what I have been asked to do. Unfortunately I don't have a choice in the technique applied, however I will definitely bring up the concerns of stepwise regression with my supervisor.

Comment: Please do bring up the serious concern, and add an eye-opening simulation of the variable selection process.   Here is an example, with code: Section 4.3 of https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf .  You'll see several other examples in the course notes where the bootstrap was used to try to replicate the variable selection process  on a real dataset.